# Check for updates periodically

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-4.0, out-of-browser, silverlight-oob

I have a SL 4.0 app running out of browser with full priviliges. How can I check for updates (CheckAndDownloadUpdateAsync()) every 10 minutes without affecting UI thread. I've tried using the Timer, but the CheckAndDownloadUpdateCompleted doesn't get executed. I think it is erroring out silently.

Thanks in advace...

Comment: Can you post the code that you have tried so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never mind, I have solved it by encapsulating the code within a class. I'm not sure what was breaking it, but this works. Maybe the issue was the Timer thread calling an event of the App class or something else, but now the timer calls the a method of the new class and it all works.

Thanks anyway...